# Tunneling HTTP PUT through POST in ADO.NET Data Services

Tags: wcf, java-me, wcf-data-services

The problem with J2ME clients consuming ADO.NET Data Services (Astoria) is that there is no support for the PUT and DELETE verbs.

Using the WCF REST Starter kit one can intercept a request to a WCF service using a new ServiceHost that exposes a property called `Interceptors` which lets you intercept requests and responses. Since Astoria is built on WCF we're home free, right?

Wrong. This technique wont work since Astoria uses another ServiceHost implementation that derives from  IDataServiceHost.

As I see it the options are:

1. Wait for a new Astoria release
2. Go raw WCF
3. Custom HTTP implementation on J2ME.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tunnel any verb to the Astoria Server via the X-Http-Method header in the payload.
We talk about this header in our protocol documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541471(PROT.10).aspx) and  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541243(PROT.10).aspx)